# Is there a setTitle() similar to getTitle() of a page element?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to set the alt title of an image in a slideshow.

Currently this is what i have tried, but for some reason it doesn't seem to update:

```
var resource = {"requests": [
          {"updatePageElementAltText": {
            "objectId": id,
            "description": "",
            "title": elementTitle
          }
          }]};
Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentationId);
```

It might be worth noting that the script is running in the Script Editor of a google sheet. The variables id, elementTitle and presentationId are all defined earlier in the script and I've checked that they are correct.

Can anyone spot the issue with this or suggest an easier way to do it?

Edit: Tanaike helped me make this specific part of the script work, but it isn't working in the larger picture, hence this edit.

What the script is supposed to do, is basically do a find/replace on all Image elements in the slideshow.

Based on keys in a sheet in Column A it should replace the Image URL in with the corresponding URL in column B. The script then cycles through all elements in the slideshow, finds the images, and then cycles through them to check if any of the titles have the 'key' as the title. The image URL should then be replaced with the URL on the same row in sheet. This part of the script is tested and works, but the key is removed from the object when the URL is updated. This shouldn't be happening as the Image should be able to be replaced again later.

For this reason, I tried to save the title before updating the URL and the put it back with the above-mentioned batchUpdate, but for some reason, it isn't working properly.

Here is the full script:

```
function imageReplacer()  {
  var newPresentationSlides = SlidesApp.openByUrl(myslidesurl).getSlides();
  var imageTitles = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(mysheeturl).getRange("'Image Replace List'!A2:A").getValues();
  var imageURLs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(mysheeturl).getRange("'Image Replace List'!B2:B").getValues();
  var presentationId = 'myslidesid';
  for (y = 0; y < newPresentationSlides.length; y++) {
    var pageElements = newPresentationSlides[y].getPageElements();
    for (x = 0; x < pageElements.length; x++) {
      for (a = 0; a < imageTitles.filter(String).length; a++) {
        if (pageElements[x].getPageElementType() == "IMAGE") {
          if(pageElements[x].asImage().getTitle() == imageTitles[a]) {
            var elementTitle = pageElements[x].asImage().getTitle();
            var id = pageElements[x].getObjectId();
            pageElements[x].asImage().replace(imageURLs[a]);
            var id = pageElements[x].getObjectId();
            var resource = {"requests": [
              {"updatePageElementAltText": {
                "objectId": id,
                "description": "Sample description",
                "title": elementTitle
              }
              }]};
            Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentationId);
          }
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the middle part of the script is exactly the same as tanaike suggested, but it's just not working properly (I even tested that specific part as a stand-alone script and it worked fine.).

Second edit:

Examples:

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1npWyONio_seI3bRibFWxiqzHxLZ-ie2wbszgROkLduE/edit#gid=0

Slides: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1rfT7TLD-O7dBbwV5V3UbugN1OLOnBI2-CZN2GPnmANM/edit#slide=id.p

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your script works. You can confirm the updated result on the slide.

But if you want to retrieve the title and description using Slides services like `getTitle()` and `getDescription()` after the title and description are updated using Slides API, it seems that those results are not updated. The updated results couldn't be retrieved even if `saveAndClose()` is used. And also, unfortunately, in the current stage, I couldn't find the methods like `setTitle()` and `setDescription()` in my environment. So how about this workaround? In this workaround, the title and description are updated by Slides API and those are retrieved by Slides API.

#### Sample script:

```
var presentationId = "###"; // Please set this.
var objectId = "###"; // Please set this.

// Update title and description
var resource = {"requests": [
  {"updatePageElementAltText": {
    "objectId": objectId,
    "description": "Sample description",
    "title": "Sample title"
  }
}]};
Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentationId);

// Retrieve updated title and description
var res = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
var slides = res.slides;
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  var pe = slides[i].pageElements;
  for (var j = 0; j < pe.length; j++) {
    if (pe[j].objectId == objectId) {
      Logger.log(pe[j].title)
      Logger.log(pe[j].description)
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- If you use this script, please enable Slides API at Advanced Google Services and API console.

#### References:

- [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)

If I misunderstand what you want, I'm sorry.

### Edit:

- You want to replace all images in Slides.
- At this time, you want to search the title of each image and replace the image from URL using the title.
- When the images are replaced, you don't want to change the title (key) of each image.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- It seems that when the image is replaced, the title of image is cleared.

  - In order to avoid this, when the image is replaced, it also puts the title. For this situation, batchUpdate of Slides API is used.
- From the viewpoint of the process cost, at first, it creates the request body and requests the request body. By this, this situation can be achieved by only one API call.

#### Modified script:

```
function imageReplacer() {
  var spreadsheetId = "### spreadsheetId ###"; // Please modify this.
  var sheetName = "Image Replace List";
  var presentationId = "### presentationId ###"; // Please modify this.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues().filter(function(e) {return e[0] && e[1]});
  var s = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var slides = s.getSlides();
  var requests = slides.reduce(function(reqs, slide) {
    var r = slide.getPageElements().reduce(function(ar, e) {
      if (e.getPageElementType() == "IMAGE") {
        var key = values.filter(function(v) {return v[0] == e.getTitle()});
        if (key.length == 1) {
          var id = e.getObjectId();
          var rq = [
            {"replaceImage":{"imageObjectId":id, "url": key[0][1]}},
            {"updatePageElementAltText":{"objectId":id, "title": key[0][0]}}
          ];
          Array.prototype.push.apply(ar, rq);
        }
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    if (r.length > 0) Array.prototype.push.apply(reqs, r);
    return reqs;
  }, []);
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, presentationId);
}
```

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about the maximum number of requests for one API call. So if you want to replace a lot of images, if the error due to this occurs, please modify above script.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't seem to figure out what's going on for my code. You can see the entire thing in this pastebin, maybe you can figure out what's wrong:
https://pastebin.com/Udp7VaqV

The code you pasted definitely solved what I was asking, but for some reason it just isn't working when I'm running it as part of my loop.

Comment: @Jonas Bæk I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Can you provide the detail information about ``for some reason it just isn't working when I'm running it as part of my loop.``? Because the script in your comment is different from your question, in order to understand correctly want you what to do, more information is required. If you can do, can you update your question? I would like to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this. I've updated the original question with the full script as well as an explanation of what is supposed to happen.

Comment: @Jonas Bæk Thank you for updating. I cannot still understand what you want to do, because your updated question is large different from the initial one. I cannot see the vision of result you want. So can you provide a sample slide and spreadsheet including the input and output you want? And what means of ``I even tested that specific part as a stand-alone script and it worked fine.``? I think that it is also important to understand correctly your current situation. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. If you cannot provide those information, please tell me.

Comment: Basically, what i want to do is to be able to have several images in a slideshow-template that can be replaced with image urls from a sheet.
I've build it to work sort of like a find and replace, so it finds all titles with the key in column A and replaces these images with the image in column B at the corresponding key.
That part is working, but it removes the titles after replacing the URL, making the 'template' functionality not really working. I've updated with example sheet and slides.

Comment: @Jonas Bæk Thank you for replying and sharing samples. But I cannot access your samples. Could you please confirm about it?

Comment: Sorry about that! I've changed the sharing settings now.

Comment: @Jonas Bæk Thank you for updating. I could access them. And I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstand what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much - this does the job perfectly!

Comment: @Jonas Bæk I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.